# Disable Printing in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, printing

Is there a way to disable printing in Internet Explorer without writing a shell around the browser API? A GPO would be the best method, but I'm certainly open for anything.

Comment: In the context of Windows operating systems, a Group Policy Object.

Comment: Are you asking the question from the perspective of a web designer or as a system administrator?

Comment: @digitallnet - for the record - why do you want to block this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are registry settings to do so.  [For example](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/442/).

Comment: Don't know why you got down voted, so i'm voting you back up, this is probably the most correct answer so far.  Actually provides a way of blocking saving the file also.

Comment: Control of the machine is implied in the question.

Comment: We will have control of the machine and this should work perfectly fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Kibbee Chances are, this poster got downvotes for a URL without clarifying content here at StackOverflow.  The model here is to have a good, local explanation *then* references elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

This is a difficult one, but in order to block printing, at least the content but not the paper, on a previous project of mine, I used the following:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    body {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

When they print the page, it is blank.

Comment: Tricky, but could be easily circumvented.

Comment: True, but most common users won't realize this.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to prevent by disabling printing?  If you're trying to stop them from printing stuff and taking it home, there's a couple different ways around that, without printing.  Including

1. Copy and paste to Word
2. Screen Shots
3. File -> Save As
4. Look through the cache files and grab it from there.

Comment: It's basically at a kiosk type of system where another application runs that has to support printing so anyone going through the above steps would probably get noticed. I think it's more of a simple prevention they need. If someone is going through that stuff, more power to them.